# derived class goes through its constructor but initialized as another derived class in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

```
  class Snakewomen : public Monster {
public:
    Snakewomen(Dungeon* dg, int r, int c) :Monster(dg, m_hp, 3, 2, 3, r, c, 'S', "Snakewomen ")
    {
        m_hp = randInt(3, 6);
        wield(new MagicFang());
    }
    ~Snakewomen() {}
    string move();

private:
    int m_hp;
};

class Bogeymen : public Monster {
public:
    Bogeymen(Dungeon* dg, int r, int c) :Monster(dg, m_hp, 2, randInt(2,3), randInt(2,3), r, c, 'B', "Bogeymen ")
    {
        m_hp = randInt(5, 10);
        wield(new ShortSword());
    }
    ~Bogeymen() {}
    string move();

private:
    int m_hp;
};
```

A monster is an actor. Both of these are monsters thus actors. Both of these classes, are created and constructed the exact same way and inserted in an array of monsters m_monsters[i]. All other monsters are being created fine  but when a Snakewomen is created, it iterates through its constructor but returns Bogeyman with the stats of a Snakewomen.

```
switch(WHICH[1]) {
    case 1:
        m_monster[index] = new Snakewomen(this, r, c);
        break;
    case 2:
        m_monster[index] = new Goblin(this, r, c);
        break;
    case 3:
        m_monster[index] = new Bogeymen(this, r, c);
```

Here are the parent classes constructors:

```
Actor(Dungeon* dg,int health, int armor, int strength, int dexterity, int r, int c,char symbol,string name)
        :m_health(health), m_armor(armor), m_str(strength), m_dex(dexterity), m_row(r), m_col(c),m_dungeon(dg),m_symbol(symbol),m_name(name),m_maxHealth(100)
    {
        m_sleep = 0;//starts out awake
    }


Monster(Dungeon* dg, int hp, int armor, int stren, int dex, int r, int c,char symbol,string name) :Actor(dg,hp, armor, stren, dex,r,c,symbol,name)
    {}
```

[Here is what the compiler sees in m_monster[index]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y08XM.png)

Comment: Can you show us some code that repro's the issue you describe? Can you show us the constructors for the base class(es)? I note that you use `m_hp` in the constructor list before you initialize it, which could lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Please don't link to code, error messages or similar. Stackoverflow questions should be self contained with *all* relevant information directly *in the question*.

Comment: It seems like `m_hp` should be lifted into `Monster`.

Comment: I  have added the parent classes constructor and will try m_hp

Comment: It worked thanks a lot!